# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NOINTERNET

Tags: networking, dns

About 2 weeks ago I decided to move to Ubuntu instead of Windows 10.

After that problems in network appeared, suddenly the web page show 'DNS_PROBE_STARTED'
then it changes to 'DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NOINTERNET'.
This problem happened most of the time when I first open the laptop (It happened suddenly sometimes), especially when the network that I connect to on the startup is different from the one that I was connected to before I close my laptop.

Restarting my laptop solves the problem.

The problem is not in the router since it appears on every router I tried, and it's not on the browser only (I've tested it in terminal).

Also I tried restarting the network manager but it does not help.

Does anyone know what I should do?

#Edit:
I tried to ping my router and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure you are in fact connected to a network, and that your computer is getting an ip. Press CTRL + ALT + T to open a terminal, and then type ping . Common router ips are 10.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, and 192.168.1.1 If it outputs lots of messages starting with "64 bytes from", then you are connected. If it gives a message that starts with "Request timeout for", than you aren't connected to a network, and you may want to look at your DHCP settings, or look up common problems when connecting ubuntu to the internet.

If you are connected to a network, than you most likely have a DNS configuration problem. In your terminal, type sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf and enter your password. Note that you won't be able to see your password as you type it. After you can see the file, you will want to modify a few things. Look for lines that start with nameserver. If there are lines that start with nameserver, delete them. Once there are none, add these two to the bottom of the file: nameserver 8.8.8.8  and nameserver 8.8.4.4 Then press CTRL + X, then y, and then enter. Then type this command: sudo service network-manager restart That should fix your problem if it was a dns issue.

If this doesn't solve it, you may want to look up how to clear firewall rules in linux.

Comment: I tried to ping my router (even though wifi settings shows that I am connected) and it fails, what can I do?

Comment: Try manually configuring everything in your network settings. Also, you may have firewall rules in place that prevent you from accessing the internet. If manually configuring your network doesn't work, you may want to do some research on how to clear firewall rules in linux.